# While loop increment position

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, printing, increment

So when I write this block of code:

```
i = 0
while i < 50:
    i += 1
    print(i)
```

it loops till the end which is 50, but when I change the increment position below the print statement:

```
i = 0
while i < 50:
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

it only loops until 49, I wanted to know what's the difference between the 2 cases?

Comment: In the first case you print `i` after incrementing it and in the second case you print it before incrementing it?! It loops to 50 in both cases, but you only print it before it is incremented from 49 to 50.

Answer (score 0):

In the first script **while condition** has to stop the increment of i by 1 while i < 50  so the last increment is 49 + 1 which equals to 50 :-), you see clearly that the condition is successfull since we do not get 50+1.

In the second script the while statement is restricting the print of the increment to i < 50 so simply 50 will not be printed.

So in the 1st script, while condition is in relation with **count**  and the second  is in relation with  **print**.

Answer (score -1):

1. In the first case, it will loop until it reaches 50 since the condition states that so long as the (I)is less than 50 , python will loop until the value evaluates to 50
2. In the second case, python will loop so long as the value is less than 50 hence it will only get to 49

Comment: the `for` loop goes to <50 in both cases, the difference is the `print` command coming after or before incrementing the `i`.